# What are the various LEGO motors that have been produced over the years?

Tags: mindstorms, motor, power-functions

RCX, NXT, WeDO, EV3, Technic etc.
How many different motors have been released over the years??

Answer (score 8):

For a comprehensive enumeration and measurements on all motors, refer to Philo's excellent page on this topic: http://www.philohome.com/motors/motorcomp.htm

There are some LEGO motors that are missing from this list since they predate the 9V era, like the [4.5V motor](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/870_Technical_Motor,_4.5V), or the [4.5V train motor](http://rebrickable.com/parts/564c01), but these are probably only of interest if you already own them, in which case you don't need to be told about them :)

There are other elements that might be considered motors, like the [PF servo motor](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=99498c01&idColor=86#T=C&C=86) (Thanks to Phil B.), but one might argue that the servo motor is not a motor in the strict sense, since it has a fixed range of movement instead of being able to turn continuously.

Also there are pieces that incorporate motors with other functional elements, like the main part of the [4095-1 Record and Play](http://brickset.com/sets/4095-1/Record-and-Play) set, the [Spybotics module](http://www.brickowl.com/catalog/lego-spybotics-receiver-assembly), the [Micro Scout in the Droid Developer Kit](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/9748_Droid_Developer_Kit) or the [Cybermaster main unit](http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/8483-1).

The WeDo theme uses a Power Functions M motor ([Source](http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/LEGO%C2%AE_WeDo%E2%84%A2_Construction_Set)).

Comment: Another missing motor is the [PF Servo motor](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=99498c01&idColor=86#T=C&C=86) from 2012 - only appeared in a few sets so far.